# UITableViewCell - Best place to set up the cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've been playing around with custom cells in a UITableViewController by have a base cell (BaseCell - subclass of UITableViewCell) and then subclasses of BaseCell (Sub1Cell, Sub2Cell, both subclasses of BaseCell).

Because the subclasses share some of the same features, if I set them up completely in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I start to repeat code for each cell type. Is there a good place, and is it good practice, to put generic set up code inside the actual custom UITableViewCell class? Currently I've written a simple setup method:

```
- (void)setupCell
{
    self.picture.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.picture.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.picture.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
    self.picture.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
}
```

I've just been calling this once I create my cell:

```
Sub1Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:statusCellIdentifier];
[cell setupCell];
```

Is there a method I can use that will be called automatically? I tried -(void) prepareForReuse but it, obviously, isn't called every time, and only when cells are being reused.

Any advice on the best way to go about this?

**Edit:**

It seems is actually being called every time I call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I was a bit confused with the correct way to create a custom cell. Should I be doing something along the lines of:

```
Sub1Cell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[Sub1Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    [cell setupCell];
}
```

If I don't do anything with the style passed, will it affect my custom cell?

Comment: Are you using storyboards (dynamic prototypes) or a separate xib file for the cell, or adding all content in code?

Comment: A storyboard with dynamic prototypes to lay out things like UILabels and UIImageViews, then setting the content and other settings in code. Is this the best approach for iOS 5?

Comment: Yes, perfect. I've answered below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `awakeFromNib` in your cell subclasses. This will be called when a new cell is created from the prototype in your storyboard, but not when a cell is re-used.

If you are using prototypes then the whole if (cell == nil) thing goes away, UITableView handles all that for you within the dequeue method.

Comment: While we're on this topic, is there a 'best practice' for where to set up cells, between `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and the cell's class? I'm thinking I'll set things like UI properties in the cell's class but set the actual content in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Does that sound like a good way to approach this? The other approach would be to add some data (such as a NSDictionary) to the cell itself so it can populate itself with content.

Answer (score 2):

In the custom cell class, provide a init method, to initialize. some codes like below:

```
- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)cellIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier])
    {
        self.picture.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
        self.picture.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.picture.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
        self.picture.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: you seem to have a return statement in a void method :D

Comment: The default return type is id for these methods. I will try this approach again. Do you know if passing UITableViewCellStyleDefault to the super's init changes the cell's appearance at all?

Comment: @ChristopherOldfield the cell's appearance is all controlled by yourself. add any view you want to the cell's contentView.  Define this method within you BaseCell class. this solution is for programming customize table cell.

Comment: @WubaoLi :) (blablabla for comment length)

Answer (score 0):

That looks ok. As long as you're only calling it at cell creation rather than in every pass through `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Not sure which you're doing from your sample code.

You might try to put your code in your custom cell's `drawRect`: to see what happens. Note that this can get *tricky* for custom cells; you might need to think about customizing `layoutSubviews` as well.

Also, for what it's worth, setting those particular CALayer properties can have a slowing effect due to offscreen rendering, but I think it won't be a big deal for you, as if should only be happening at cell creation.

UPDATE

I think you will want to separate the initial setup code from the code that updates the content of the cell during table view operation. The initial setup code, which it seems to me is what you've written above, should only be run once, at cell creation. So I'm taking back what I wrote in the 2nd paragraph, above; don't put it in `drawRect:`.

MORE

Check out Apple's docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1). I'm not sure the effect of passing cell style... if in your override of `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` you pass the style to super, then yes, I would think that super would use it to set up the cell's content view. If you then modify the content view with your own stuff, then super is doing wasted work. As for the rest of the code you added under 'Edit:', I think it looks good.

For what it's worth, whenever I do this, I use InterfaceBuilder.

Comment: I can't read that here, please add the code to your original question

Comment: Just realised you can't do proper formatting in the replies. Added it to the question. Cheers.

Comment: One of my initial approaches was to put the setup code in 'initWithStyle' but I couldn't get it to work. Ideally that's where I'd like to put it, as it seems to make the most sense.

I have been laying out the cell in Interface Builder, but for changing details I have to change in code I wanted it to happen during cell creation.