# awakeFromNib() called twice in UICollectionViewCell subclass at scroll start

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have custom `UICollectionViewCell` in xib. 
When `ViewController` is loaded - `awakeFromNib()` in cell subclass called 6 times (the screen initially placed 6 cells, ok), BUT when i start to scroll, `awakeFromNib()` is called six times more, causing lag. But after this "re-load" scrolling begins to work smoothly. This happens only the first time at scroll start. `dequeueReusableCell`, obviously, is used.
With `UITableView` instead collection the situation is similar.
Feel like the next 6 cells are loaded from the xib again (in the collection of just 100+ cells), ignoring reuse. 
What could be the problem?

For clarity:

`UIColectionView` with Vertical scroll direction, two cells in line. When ViewController loaded i see 6 cells on screen and 6 `awakeFromNib` calls in console.

I start scroll down to 7-8 cells, before their appearance on the screen i see lag and 2 calls of `awakeFromNib` method.

Similarly for the following two pairs of cells.

After this scroll begins work fine, until cells 99-100+, and awakeFromNib is never invoked.

**Added:**
OK, here's what I found out:

I have a subView inside a collectionView (header like in `UITableView`), and, accordingly, collectionViewLayout set sectionInsets top = height of header. If I remove the header, and make the top insets, for example: -180 (about excluding the height of NavigationBar, so the screen initially fit 12 cells and the scroll lag is gone.

Ie, the system needs to load from the xib at all the cells that will be one-time visible on the screen and reuse them in future. (But why not one time load xib and reuse it immediately for all other initially cells?)

And now the question - how to fix it?

**Added.2**

Working solution - add header in `viewDidAppear` method of ViewController, but this... hm.. not good.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a known side effect (or purposeful design?) of UICollectionView & UITableView. Here's a related question (talking about NSTableView, but the concepts/issues are the same):

[awakeFromNib method called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092366/awakefromnib-method-called-multiple-times)

Your collection view initially displays six cells to start with, but it sounds like iOS is allocating six more cells to allow for scrolling left & right.  So there are at least 12 (reuseable) cells in memory.

If you're doing a lot of work in `awakeFromNib` (which is what's contributing to the lag), you might want to try to determine how to optimize things.

You can also find some additional helpful hints in this related question:

[UITableViewCell - Best place to set up the cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460469/uitableviewcell-best-place-to-set-up-the-cell)

Comment: if i comment out `awakeFromNib()` method - lags at scroll start will still be. This means that the .xib is loaded again? but why?

Comment: A dozen copies of your UICollectionViewCell & UITableViewCell are being instantiated, in order to be able to properly scroll & populate the visible section of your collection view and table view.  You should try to figure out where the lag in your cell subclasses are coming from.  I suggest using [Xcode's Time Profiler instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Instrument-TimeProfiler.html).  Here's a tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started

Comment: But these copies must be initialized at load of the controller, and not as the beginning of the scroll? looks crazy.
I see call of `awakeFromNib` method only when next 6 cells (7-12) visible on screen, at this time, when i see `awakeFromNib` call - scroll laggy, very well seen on the old ipad 2, when scrolling stops before the next pair of cells begin visible. 
After when in will appears on the screen 12 cell scrolling begins to work smoothly in all directions, and `awakeFromNib` is no longer invoked.
in Instruments at this time in the top - cellForItemAtIndexPath
p.s: sorry for my english

Comment: For clarity: 

`UIColectionView` with Vertical scroll direction, two cells in line. When ViewController loaded i see 6 cells on screen and 6 `awakeFromNib` calls in console. 

I start scroll down to 7-8 cells, before their appearance on the screen i see lag and 2 calls `awakeFromNib`.

Similarly for the following two pairs of cells.

After this scroll begins work fine, until cells 98-100+, and `awakeFromNib` is never invoked.

Comment: this is sounding less and less like a problem with `awakeFromNib` and more like a problem with how you are configuring & setting up your cells.  It might be worthwhile to show some code in your question?  e.g. your `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: I tried to simplify method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to: `return collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)` and commented out all overrided methods in cell subclass. This has no effect...

Comment: Please, see my question, i added founded information. Thank.